# Папки и файлы созданные приложением не видны при подключении с ПК

Tags: android, файлы

Приложение создаёт папку и файл. Но при подключении с ПК их не видно.

Что я делаю не так. Мой код:

```
File f = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "log.txt");
if (!f.exists()) {
    f.createNewFile();
}
```

Comment: я сталкивался с такой ошибкой, не смог победить, просто в самом устройстве копировал эти файлы в другую папку (того же устройства), а потом уже эти фалы видны на ПК.

Comment: @Style-7, как оказалось нужно повторно сканировать путь (см. ответ).

Comment: Спасибо попробую

Answer (score 1):

Ответ нашёл сам.

Нужно добавить путь к файлу в список повторно сканируемых путей.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{f.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);
```