# Файлы созданные приложением не обновляются при подключении устройства к ПК

Tags: android, логирование

Создаю файлы как описано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/975527/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%9F%D0%9A).

На устройстве всё нормально отображается и данные и размер. При подключении к ПК пустые файлы.

В чём может быть причина?

P.S. Файлы смотрю через проводник Windows.

Comment: Предполагаю вы смотрите их через "Device File Explorer"?

Comment: Файлы смотрю через проводник Windows.

Comment: Вы их пробовали скопировать на ПК? До боли знакомая проблема, но не могу вспомнить в чём там было, вроде что-то с доступом, я их сразу даже не мог скопировать с телефона, но уже точно не скажу