# Не видны создаваемые файлы

Tags: android

При захождении с компьютера по USB в телефон не видны некоторые папки и файлы которые создаёт моё приложение. Заходя непосредственно через телефон (не через компьютер) я их прекрасно вижу, как и из компьютера если их вырезать/скопировать из папки и перебросить в новое место. Причём текстовые всегда видны, а фото и видео - нет. Как только я не переименовывал и как не указывал путь сохранения (естественно, английские буквы без символов). Использую только внутреннюю память телефона. При использовании не моих файлов компьютер обнаруживает в телефоне всё и всегда.  Проблема исчезает при перезагрузке телефона, но хотелось бы как то по проще.

Comment: Покажите метод сохранения файла. Встречал подобное поведение на lenovo.

Comment: попробуйте как здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/975527/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%9f%d0%9a#comment1638159_975527

Answer (score 1):

Проблема не в вашей программе, а в реализациях MTP в винде и некоторых телефонах. Содержимое папок кэшируется и вы продалжаете видеть удаленные на телефоне файлы и не видите созданные. Вы не в силах с этим что-то внятное сделать, только переподключать/перезагружать телефон, а то и компьютер. Если вдруг телефон предлагает при подключении выбрать вариант MSC - может он поможет, но не факт